# Mongoose not saving document completely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

I am trying to save data to my mongo db using mongoose. But unfortunately I am not able to save it completely. However it creates a data array but defaults like company name etc. are not saving. However these values are not available in requested body

[image]

I am using:

```
var seller = new sellers(req.body);

  seller.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('An user with this email id or mobile number already exist');
    }
    res.status(200).send('You have successfully registered');
})
```

Comment: add what is in req.body json data in the question?

Comment: Requested body do not have this information, so it should save the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use a pre save hook to set an object as the default in your array:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.data.length == 0) {

        var default = {
            fieldName: 'Company Name',
            fieldValue: 'No Information Provided',
            // etc.
        };

        this.data.push(default);

    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: But other default values are working.. as shown in attached image. Why only this nested one is not working ?

Comment: The 'data' field is of type array so it will itself default to an empty array.

Comment: So, should I keep it as object?

Comment: If you want an array of objects and to have a default object set, then use the pre-save hook.